# Docker-compose on production or manual AWS setup?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, docker-compose

I'm a newbie with AWS.

Actually I work on a project and we use docker-compose in development.

It compose of 2 database (postgresql and redis), 3 microservices and Nginx.

I don't know if the best is to use docker-compose on AWS or create 2 database with RDS on AWS, 3 EC2 container and use the API gateway.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would look into using RDS for PostgreSQL and ElastiCache for Redis. For your microservices I would look into using the ECS service, or possibly just Docker on EC2. You could do the same thing with Nginx, depending on what you are using that for. You might want to look into using an Application Load Balancer instead of, or in addition to, your Nginx server.

Comment: Thanks, any idea of the cost ?

Comment: You didn't provide anywhere near enough information to estimate the costs. You'll need to spend some time using this tool to estimate your AWS costs: https://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html

Answer (score 1):

For a completely automated approach, you can use CloudFormation to build your RDS and API gateway. This same CF template can deploy your docker-compose pointing to your newly created instances. This way you have a completely portable and self sufficient script.